# Mysql - getting distinct records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySql table (user_actions) with the following columns:
id, user_id, created_at, action_type

I want a sql query that will get the latest actions that the user performed with no duplication of the actions.

for example: 
user_id 1 has 3 records that has the action_type "follow"
and 2 records that has the action_type "unfollow"

in this case i want the query to return two records, one with action_type "follow" and one with "unfollow"

any thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean you want the latest ocurrences of each kind of actions the user has ever performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select ua.* 
from user_actions ua
join (select max(id) as max_id,user_id,action_type from user_action group by user_id,user_action) ua_max
on ua.id=ua_max.max_id and ua.user_id=ua_max.user_id and ua.action_type=ua_max.action_type
```

Comment: If the id is a primary key, then you actually only need the `ua.id=ua_max.max_id` in the join condition, but +1 for the approach.

Comment: yes you are right :) .. I am with my head in other places :))

Comment: This is a good query if there are more fields in the table, and also if id is not pk then date can be put instead and the query will work as is.

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQL's group by clause for this:

```
select user_id, action_type, max(created_at)
  from user_actions
 group by user_id, action_type
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select * from user_actions where action_type, created_at in 
   (select action_type, max(created_at) from user_actions group by action_type);
```

Comment: This query is equivalent to `select * from user_actions` except that it is more expensive for the db to execute.

Comment: @a'r: I agree, I didn't intend it that way, made the mistake of saving it earlier, please see me edited query.